# Xamarin, Windows 10 Parallels and connecting to a MAC based Android Emulator

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator

I am trying to get my Parallels Visual Studio install to talk to the Android Studio Emulators on my MAC (for whatever reason I am struggling to start the windows ones such as Android Player / Microsoft Android Emulator as they ask for Hyper-V or whatever etc).

Also, having it connect to my MAC reduces the need to install emulators on every VM instance.

I have followed the steps in this guide -

[https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-android-emulator-on-osx-using-parallels/](https://web.archive.org/web/20180219030040/http://taco.visualstudio.com:80/en-us/docs/run-android-emulator-on-osx-using-parallels/)

And after I run the putty SSH script to connect to the MAC, I sadly cannot see any emulators using

```
adb devices
```

But, if I run from windows command prompt after the script has connected -

```
adb connect localhost:5555
```

I then see via

```
adb devices 

List of devices attached
emulator-5554 offline
```

So it is "sort of" connecting, but the device is registering as offline and I cannot seem to do anything to get it online so that it could finally show up in the Xamarin Visual Studio Device list.

Does anyone have experience of this who could help out? Is this doable for Xamarin Visual Studio?

*NOTES*

I have tried kill-server / start-server on both machines to no avail to remove the offline

Comment: You could try and connect directly to the IP: `adb connect 192.x.y.z`. This does not require any SSH.

Comment: Hi @Krumelur, I do not seem to be able to get an IP for an Android Studio based emulator (or started via emulator -avd command in terminal), Android Player from xamarin provides this as I think Genymotion does.  Maybe there is a way?

Comment: Try this in the emulators browser: https://www.whatismyip.com

Comment: That gives me my public IP address of my MAC, I can get an internal 10.* IP address using adb shell, but I cannot get it to help me connect to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you WickedW, I'm glad it helped!

So the solution is:

> I had the same problem and I found that if Xamarin studio is running on Mac, it will block ports 5554 and 5555. Close it, run in Parallels Windows `adb kill-server` (Visual Studio will restart it) and restart the SSH connection.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to "bitibi" on -

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/249573#Comment_249573

I always had Xamarin Studio open during a working day when trying to fix this, and it was basically blocking the ports, soon as turned off Xamarin Studio and re-tried the process, all started working!!

Answer (score 1):

Another option for connecting from Visual Studio inside Parallels to the emulator on the Mac. This one doesnt require SSH or saving the password in cleartext

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/connect-android-emulator-mac-windows